# I run Python in TextWrangler and it works fine but on Mac Terminal it doesn't

Tags: python, terminal, textwrangler

Python code:

```
"<stdin>"
#!/usr/bin/env
print "Hello world!" 
print "How are you?"
```

The above is some code that I applied onto a script and it works when run in TextWrangler, but when I put it in Terminal, it fails.

Why is this happening? Does it have to do with the way I open the file?

Comment: "<stdin>"
#!/usr/bin/env
print "Hello world!" 
print "How are you?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/usr/bin/env` is not the correct path to Python. Most likely the shebang line should read:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

I am pretty sure it needs to be the first line, so delete the `"<stdin>"` line as well (that's ignored by Python anyway).

Also make sure you have set the execute permission on the script: `chmod +x /path/to/script.py`

Comment: When he formatted the coding with blocks, it corrupted. I edited in the correct formatting, but it hasn't updated yet. The second line (of 4) reads `#!/usr/bin/env`

Answer (score 1):

The line that starts with `#!` is called the [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) in Unix. By definition, two things are wrong with your shebang:

1. The sheebang MUST be the initial line in the script -- you have it on the second line.
2. If Python is the target interpreter, you either need the absolute path to Python (something like `#!/usr/bin/Python` OR an argument to env to execute the configured Python -- something like `#!/usr/bin/env Python` note the argument 'Python' to the utility [env](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env_%28shell%29)